# Do we have ChunkExecutionContext similar to StepExecutionContext in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch, chunks

```
Spring Batch Version: 2.1.8
```

We want to do something after each chunk is written, and set some data inside a context which is valid only for the chunk. This data is then used inside `ChunkListener`'s *afterChunk* method.

We can use `StepExecutionContext` to achieve this, but didn't seem totally correct.

Does anyone have more information on where to store **context information valid only for a chunk**?

Answer (score 1):

There is in fact a [ChunkContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/scope/context/ChunkContext.html) available in Spring Batch 2.1.8. To understand the lifecycle of the ChunkContext it's important to understand that the chunk is defined by the commit-interval of the Tasklet. The Tasklet is responsible for managing the lifecycle of the ChunkContext. Also see the java docs for the ChunkContext for a note about retries.

The ChunkContext is accessible through the the JobExecutionContext getChunContexts()

Comment: But, how is this accessible? And howz the life cycle of ChunkContext managed?

Comment: I edited my response to try and answer these additional questions for you.

Comment: I checked JobExecution, StepExecution and ExecutionContext classes, but couldn't find any method that could be used to getChunkContext(), could you please point me to the class that you were referring to?

Comment: would appreciate if you can answer the above questions.

Comment: Chunk context is exposed to the execute method of the Tasklet interface. See: http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/Tasklet.html

Comment: Our use case is to stuff something in ChunkContext as part of Writer (part of a read-process-write step) and read it in ChunkListener's afterChunk() method.